# How can I calculate the studentized residual per observation by group in R?

Tags: r

I am doing research on the effect of lean inventory management on the financial performance of firms and to do this I need to create a new variable.

This variable is calculated by 2 steps:

1. By regressing the natural logarithm of sales on the natural logarithm of inventory for each of the i industries (NAICS) and t years. The formula is as follows:

[image]

2. The variable for each firm (f) is obtained by studentising the residual (u) and multiplying it by -1.

So mathematically I know how I should go on to do this, but my dataset has more than 3000 observations and that is going to take ages to do by hand.

My dataset is as follows (from the dput(head())). This dataset only shows the same NAICS (315) but there are a lot more, 46 in total.

```
mydata <- structure(list(NAICS = c(315, 315, 315, 315, 315, 315), 
              Year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2016), 
              `Total Inventories` = c(487.591, 548.722, 574.226, 593.987, 599.262, 487.997), 
              `Net Sales` = c(3241.999, 3443.591, 3501.199, 3553.923, 3050.61, 2387.289)), 
              row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can anyone help me with how I can easily do this in R? All help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

**Data**

To illustrate my approach, consider the following sample data that builds on yours

```
> df
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   NAICS  Year `Total Inventories` `Net Sales`
   <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>
 1   315  2016                488.       3242.
 2   315  2017                549.       3444.
 3   315  2018                574.       3501.
 4   315  2019                594.       3554.
 5   315  2020                599.       3051.
 6   315  2016                488.       2387.
 7   320  2016                488.       3242.
 8   320  2017                549.       3444.
 9   320  2018                574.       3501.
10   320  2019                594.       3554.
11   320  2020                599.       3051.
12   320  2016                488.       2387.
```

**Step 1**

First, you split your dataframe according to the `NAICS` values with the help of

```
> df_list <- split(df, df$NAICS)
> df_list
$`315`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  NAICS  Year `Total Inventories` `Net Sales`
  <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>
1   315  2016                488.       3242.
2   315  2017                549.       3444.
3   315  2018                574.       3501.
4   315  2019                594.       3554.
5   315  2020                599.       3051.
6   315  2016                488.       2387.

$`320`
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  NAICS  Year `Total Inventories` `Net Sales`
  <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>
1   320  2016                488.       3242.
2   320  2017                549.       3444.
3   320  2018                574.       3501.
4   320  2019                594.       3554.
5   320  2020                599.       3051.
6   320  2016                488.       2387.
```

**Step 2**

Then you use `lapply()` to go over all data.frames in that list, estimating the model and using the function `rstud()` from the `MASS` package to calculate the studentized residuals for every firm

```
Out <- lapply(df_list, function(z) { z$stud_res <- MASS::studres(lm(log(z$`Total Inventories`) ~ log(z$`Net Sales`)))*(-1); z})
> Out
$`315`
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  NAICS  Year `Total Inventories` `Net Sales` stud_res
  <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1   315  2016                488.       3242.    2.25 
2   315  2017                549.       3444.    0.313
3   315  2018                574.       3501.   -0.153
4   315  2019                594.       3554.   -0.519
5   315  2020                599.       3051.   -1.63 
6   315  2016                488.       2387.    0.318

$`320`
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  NAICS  Year `Total Inventories` `Net Sales` stud_res
  <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1   320  2016                488.       3242.    2.25 
2   320  2017                549.       3444.    0.313
3   320  2018                574.       3501.   -0.153
4   320  2019                594.       3554.   -0.519
5   320  2020                599.       3051.   -1.63 
6   320  2016                488.       2387.    0.318
```

**Final Output**

```
> Out
$`315`
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  NAICS  Year `Total Inventories` `Net Sales` stud_res
  <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1   315  2016                488.       3242.    2.25 
2   315  2017                549.       3444.    0.313
3   315  2018                574.       3501.   -0.153
4   315  2019                594.       3554.   -0.519
5   315  2020                599.       3051.   -1.63 
6   315  2016                488.       2387.    0.318

$`320`
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  NAICS  Year `Total Inventories` `Net Sales` stud_res
  <dbl> <dbl>               <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1   320  2016                488.       3242.    2.25 
2   320  2017                549.       3444.    0.313
3   320  2018                574.       3501.   -0.153
4   320  2019                594.       3554.   -0.519
5   320  2020                599.       3051.   -1.63 
6   320  2016                488.       2387.    0.318
```

Comment: Amazing! This exactly what I need! Thank you so much! You're a life saver!

Comment: Very glad to help :-) You can check the mark if the question is settled.

Comment: Hmm it seems there is a problem. When I run the lapply to estimate the residual (the final step) I get this error code: `Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :     NA/NaN/Inf in 'y' `. There are no na's in my dataset. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I suppose the log transformation of some of the input variables is ill-defined due to some negative values or values that are close to zero? It definitely is an error that pertains to the `lm()` step and has nothing to do with either `studres()` or `lapply()`. Make sure that **all** values of the log-transformed variables are positive and try again. Then report what you get.

Comment: I am quite new to R and not sure how to easily do all of this, so I am very grateful for your patience. So using excel I found that the log of Total Inventories has 156 negative values, but also 5 instances where total inventorues is 0 so the ln comes out as #NUM. the log of Net Sales has 28 negative values. I have no idea how te remove these out of the equation though.

Comment: Type `df <- df[df$´Total Inventories´ > 0 & df$´Net Sales´> 0, ]$`. Then try again the code from the solution.

Comment: That did the trick!! Last question. Is it possible to combine these split dataframes into one dataframe again so that I can save it as an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Nevermind. Found it! Thank you so much for helping me out! It is much appreciated!

Comment: Always happy to help!